# Store contents of a <div> to another webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xml

I want my users to be able to view content on my website, and when they see content they like (My website randomly generates content using `JQuery.load()` ), I would like them to be able to store it onto a personal page that they have to log in to, to see.

My page loads content with the line:

```
$(".resultContent").load(skillList[skillChoice]);
```

The variable "`SkillList`" is assigned "`skills.html #id`"

the '`#id`' part is identifying a `<div>`, and that's the part I want to be stored, and I want the user to be able to store multiple parts of the page skills.html on their personal page.

This sounds fairly complex, but I was wondering if it's doable, if so, what language(s) would I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to save those html snippet on the server, mostly likely in a database. This can be done by client-side javascript, an ajax POST. The server side can use any language.
2. Since you are saving some html on the server and will load that in a page. The server side **must** sanitize the html snippets for security.
3. When the html snippet is saved, the server needs to know who sends the request. That is the user needs to log in before or when s/he saves the content for later use.